# Tainted canvases may not be exported issue

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I searched all over the google but none of the answers were working :(. I want to generate a pdf with some content on my page. I am using html2canvas and jspdf to acheive that, I am using s3 to store the images, added cors configuration to s3 but still I keep on getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Html2canvas docs - https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

I tried adding crossOrigin="anonymous" but it still didn't help me to get over this error

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvsakhil/7s3myzto/11/)

In jsfiddle you can see error in the console:
[image]

Comment: Did you check the documentation of HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()? here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL 
seems like you're passing the wrong params

Comment: @Ayyash this is what I am using https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

Comment: We came to a solution and it worked but its been more than 3 years and I don't remember what we did. Sorry for that @SadikulHaqueSadi